# Цикл для выбора элемента подходящего под условие js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Итак, у меня есть массив объектов, в каждом объекте храниться время(в секундах) в которое он был записан под именем `"time"`. Я перебираю этот массив циклом, беру это время, и считаю разницу со временем на данный момент. И вот тут то мне и нужна помощь: мне необходимо сделать так, что бы если разница между ними не превышала один час код выполнялся дальше.

```
var timeNow = Date.now();
for (var i = 0; i < respond.length; i++) {
    var data = respond[i];
    var timeInMessage = data.time * 1000;
    var diff_time = (timeNow - timeInMessage);
    if(diff_time <= 3600000){
         //для каждого "time" у которого "diff_time" <= 3600000 сделать вывод на страницу
                var rowClone = $('.mess_hide').clone().removeClass('mess_hide');
                $('#messages').append(rowClone);
                $('.time', rowClone).html(res);
                $('.name', rowClone).html(data.user);
                $('.message', rowClone).html(data.message);
                $('.scroller').scrollTop($('#messages').height()); 
    }

<div class="scroller">
    <table id="messages">
        <tr class="mess_hide">
            <td class="time"></td>
                <td class="name"></td>
                <td class="message"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
     </div>
        <form method="POST" id="easyForm">
            <input type="text" name="text" id="text">
            <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
```

Так выглядит  `console.log(data)`

`Object {time: "1499882893", user: "Max", message: "Hello"}`

Подскажите,как я могу это осуществить?

Comment: Ну так добавляете в html какую-то таблицу и с помощью appendChild вставляете строки с нужными данными.

Comment: Вместо `data.time * 1000` каждый раз проще сделать единожды `timeNow = Date.now()/1000`

Comment: @br3t обновил вопрос, это всё есть. Проблема в создании самого цикла(очень я в это слаб)не могу выбрать нужные мне массивы с подходящим `time`.

Comment: @br3t Мне удобней с мс работать.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, в чем проблема с циклом. Выглядит нормально.

Comment: @br3t Давайте так: у меня в `data` два объекта, в узнав их `diff_time` выяснилось что по условию подходит только один из  них. Вопрос: как мне выбрать именно подходящий и сделать вывод его времени?

Comment: Вот пример https://jsfiddle.net/8df057te/ , на 90% из вашего кода + эмуляция таймштампов